# How do I get PrimeFaces DataTable to sort?

Tags: jsf, datatable, primefaces

I just can't get sorting working. I'm not sure if this should be posted in the Rain forums, because I am just using PrimeFaces for the first time, and purchased/installed the Rain layout. So I'm not sure whether Rain is causing this or not.

I define a standard p:dataTable and use:

```
<p:column headerText="Name" field="name" filterMatchMode="contains" />
```

And sort does not work.

Here is my p:dataTable definition:

```
<p:dataTable id="table" widgetVar="table" stripedRows="true" reflow="true"
  value="#{viewBean.dtos}"
  var="dto" selection="#{viewBean.dtos}" rowKey="#{dto.id}" paginator="true"
  rows="10" rowSelectMode="add">
```

My PrimeFaces version:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.primefaces/primefaces -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
    <version>10.0.0-RC2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: What is the scope of your bean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a PrimeFaces version that has some bugs related to sort/filter data tables.
Like this:
[`DataTable`/`TreeTable`: `sortBy` not working with client saving state method](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/6987)

You can apply the workarond, but you may face other issues, so
it will be better if you switch to PrimeFaces 11, using the: [PrimeFaces migration guide 10.0.0 -> 11.0.0](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/11_0_0/#/../migrationguide/11_0_0)

Comment: sortBy isnt required if field is defined